# Problem with wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, dotnet

I want to play osu! on ubuntu and wanted to instal dotnet but then came this error message: `This package (dotnet20) does not work on a 64-bit installation. You must use a prefix made with WINEARCH=win32`. So i did that but when i wanted to do this there came many errors

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/sean/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0017:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0017:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
001b:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
001b:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
001b:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0010:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0010:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x6d5d3018
001d:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x6a0cb608, context 0x8d88c8, init_notify 0, handle 0x111fc78): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/sean/.wine' has been updated.
```

and because im a noob in things ubuntu, i wanted to ask here how to fix it

Comment: According to [this](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=28637) WineHQ post, the error may be caused by not `cd`-ing to the directory first. Please comment back if you have other questions. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

To run 32 bit applications with wine you have to add the concerning architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

For more details see: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Then using a 32 bit WINEPREFIX may be obsolete.

Comment: i did that before that but i restarted the PC next day and then it worked but thx for the answer